# Probability of radio-active decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radiation

There are two radio nuclei $A$ and $B$. $A$ is an alpha emitter and $B$ is a beta emitter. Their disintegration constants are in the ratio of $1:2$. What should be the ratio of the number of atoms of two types at time $t = 0$ so that probabilities of getting alpha and beta particles are same at that instant?

Comment: What is the disintegration constant? Half life? Or the time constant of their decay rate?

Comment: Only their ratio is given.

Comment: I am sorry but in my opinion your problem isn't that you can't solve this task, but that you can't ask a clear question.

Comment: Well, the disintegration constant is the probability of an atom decaying per unit time.  If each such decay produces one $\alpha$ or one $\beta$ respectively, what's the ratio of number of atoms you need at a given moment for the rates to be the same at that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the nuclear structure and its instability,a parent nucleus may undergo either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ emission. Sometimes a parent nucleus may undergo both types of emission with the probabilities of $\alpha$-decay or $\beta$-decay.

The amount of daughter nuclides produced by $\alpha$- and $\beta$-decays will be in the probability ratio of $\alpha$- and $\beta$-decays.

For a radioactive element with decay constant $\lambda$  which decays by both $\alpha$- and $\beta$-decays given that the probability for an $\alpha$-emission is $P_1$ and that for $\beta$-emission is $P_2$, the decay constant of the element can be split for individual modes.

Like in this case the decay constants for $\alpha$- and $\beta$-decays separately  can be given as :

$\lambda_{\alpha}=P_1\lambda$

$\lambda_{\beta}=P_2\lambda$

Use these equations to get your answer.